# Custom extended Activity not working on Nativescript 7

Tags: nativescript

Months before, same code worked fine and I was able to start custom activity (and custom application) but I don't know what happened.
I tried on new projects to reproduce steps but I always get the same error:

> Unable to create application com.tns.NativeScriptApplication:
> com.tns.NativeScriptException: Error calling module function
> System.err: Error:
> com.tns.system.classes.loading.LookedUpClassNotFound: Class
> "a.b.NativeScriptActivity" not found. System.err: File:
> (/data/data/org.nativescript.testing/files/internal/ts_helpers.js:154:25)
> System.err:  System.err: StackTrace:  System.err:
> (/data/data/org.nativescript.testing/files/internal/ts_helpers.js:154:26)
> System.err:   at
> __decorate(/data/data/org.nativescript.testing/files/internal/ts_helpers.js:13:19)
> System.err:   at ./app/core/android/activity.ts(file:
> src/app/core/android/activity.android.ts:5:25)...

Activity ts file is activity.android.ts.
I put on JavaProxy decorator "a.b.NativeScriptActivity". Same on Android Maifest.
Also added entry on AppComponents array on webpack.config.js

UPDATE: I gave up with Nativescript a long time ago (moved to Flutter).

Comment: Did you add the activity file path to webpack config?

Comment: Yes, on AppComponent array. I know that this is okay because I tried with a bad path and I can see the error. When I put correct path that error disappears

Comment: Also yo can see on trace error './app/core/android/activity.ts(file: src/app/core/android/activity.android.ts:5:25)', which is the extended Activity file.

Answer (score 1):

For `Nativescript 7` you must add following decorator :

```
 @NativeClass()
```

**example:**

```
@NativeClass()
@JavaProxy("com.lanmis.app.BackgroundJobService")
class BackgroundService extends android.app.job.JobService {
}
```

---

In `nativescript 6` :

**The first solution :**

If  **`importHelpers: true`** exists in **tsconfig.json** you must change it to :
**`importHelpers: false`**

**The second solution :**

Instead of following block :

```
@JavaProxy("com.lanmis.app.BackgroundJobService")
class BackgroundService extends android.app.job.JobService {

//Code

}
```

Use :

```
android.app.job.JobService.extend("com.lanmis.app.BackgroundJobService", {

//Code

})
```

Comment: I tried everything a long time ago without success and I discarded Nativescript in favour of Flutter which works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Lookedup class error occurs due to the activity path issue...check your webpack file for

> If appPath ="src" ,

```
      const appComponents = [
resolve(__dirname, "src/app/activity.android.ts")
]
```

or

> If appPath appPath = "app"

```
      const appComponents = [
```

resolve(__dirname, "app/activity.android.ts")
]